# how to add numbers together in the way you would print with (System.out.println(numbers)); numbers++;

Tags: java, math, sum, addition

how would i add numbers together in the same manner as if i were to print them for example.

```
    System.out.println(numbers);
    numbers++;
```

this would print like so.

```
    1
    2
    3
    4
```

etc

how would i add them together as 1+2+3+4

here is my current code on this question.
this is the exercise i am working on for my MOOC at the University of Helsinki i live in the US so its hard to ask for help because of the 8 hour time difference.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Until What?:");
    // the user inputs a number here
    int blockExe = 1;
    // the blockExe variable is supposed to store a count of how many times the
    // block has been executed which i belive should be limited to the user input
    int userIn = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    int sum = userIn + blockExe;
    // i am supposed to add the number of block executions the user input 
    // each time adding 1 to the execution so 1+2+3
    // then printing the sum of those numbers

    while (blockExe <= userIn) {
        blockExe += 1;
        if (blockExe + userIn == sum) {
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sum is:" +sum);

}
```

}

Comment: what is your sample input and what output did you get, and what outpu t do you need?

Comment: the test runner for the course will test both negative an positive numbers, so the first sample input is 6 the output i get is 4 and i need 6 so it should count it as 1+2+3=6

Answer (score 1):

This code is ambiguous:

```
while (blockExe <= userIn) {
    blockExe += 1;
    if (blockExe + userIn == sum) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Perhaps you want this:

```
int sum=0;
for(blockExe = 1;blockExe <= userIn; blockExe ++) {
    sum+=blockExe;
}
```

Comment: i do understand that this will work, however we have not covered (for) in our course yet. So far just (if, else, if-else, while, sout, and most of the mathematical opperators, variables and some of the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println("Sum is:" +sum);

That line doesn't make sense.  I think the number you are trying to output should be blockExe but it isn't really clear what you are trying to do from you description.  Try changing that line to:

System.out.println("Sum is:" blockExe);

and see if that gets you closer to your answer.